# How to reload the jtable in mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have my jtable, displaying a grid with the list loading from server.For this iam calling a method NotAllotedStudentsList,Using Search button, iam getting a new list from server by calling the same method.
My search button looks like,

```
  // Assign selected students
    $('#SearchFor').button().click(function () {
        var SearchForValue = $("#NotAllotedStudentsList").val();
        var StudentInputTypeValue = $("#InputType").val();
        alert(StudentInputTypeValue);
        var options = {};
        options.type = "POST";
        options.url = "/Dashboard/NotAllotedStudentsList/";
        options.data = JSON.stringify({ model: { SearchFor: SearchForValue, StudentInputType: StudentInputTypeValue } });
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.contentType = "application/json";
        $.ajax(options);

    });
```

i want to display the new list when my search button got clicked. But, my code does display the old list(default list which will display when the page gets loaded).Kindly tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: so u want to load the jtable data once the user types the query string..?

Comment: @Outlooker: kindly refer the formatted post.